# Creating a section with video as background HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to imitate the front page of lumosity.com but I am unable to set a video background to the section. Here's what I've done so far:

**HTML**

```
<section id="banner">
   <video id="videobcg" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0">
     <source src="https://static.lumosity.com/resources/home_page_templates/574/neuralnetwork.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
          Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
    <p>This is text that is in front of video, we do not want the z-index of video to be greater than content. Hence background!
    </p>
 </section>
```

**CSS**

```
#videobcg { 
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     padding: 5em 2em 4em 2em;
     z-index: -1000;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

As you can see my code doesn't work, the video remains hidden somewhere on the webpage. Any ideas?

Comment: http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/knqyK

Comment: here is working: https://jsfiddle.net/v9whp8m0/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used [this](http://%09%20codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/knqyK) as an example and modified your css.

**Example 1: Video as background of containing div**

In this example the video only plays as the background of the containing div, similar to lumosity.com:

[JSFIDDLE 1](https://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/8jmze5yq/2/)

```
#banner {
    position: relative;
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#videobcg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

**Example 2: Video as background of full page**

[JSFIDDLE 2](https://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/8jmze5yq/)

```
#videobcg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 1s opacity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [BIGVIDEO.JS](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/) to do the Video Background :

HTML

```
<div class="background-image-hide parallax-background video-wrap" data-video-wrap="images/slides/video.mp4" data-img-wrap="images/slides/video.jpg">
</div>
```

JS

```
var bigVedio = function() {
                // initialize BigVideo
                var BV = new $.BigVideo({
                        container: $('.video-wrap'),
                        forceAutoplay: isTouch
                    }),
                    V = $('.video-wrap').attr('data-video-wrap'),
                    img = $('.video-wrap').attr('data-img-wrap');
                if (typeof V != typeof undefined) {
                    if (!isTouch) {
                        BV.init();
                        BV.show(V, {
                            ambient: true,
                            doLoop: true
                        });
                    } else {
                        BV.init();
                        BV.show(img);
                    }
                }
            };
```

css

```
.background-image-hide {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  height: 150%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover !important;
  z-index: 0;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

Hope this will help you.